# How to create a counteranimation with decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript code which turns a text element with the class `count` into an animated counter.

The script is working well but unfortunately, it only works with non-decimal numbers.

Here is my script:

```js
function startCounter(){
    $('.count').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 3000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        });
    });
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
    startCounter();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="count">6.0</p>
<p class="count">600</p>
```

So now my question is, how can I also show the decimal numbers in the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the `Math.ceil()` with

```
Math.round(num * 100) / 100
```

in order to round to two decimal places:

```js
function startCounter(){
    $('.count').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 3000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(Math.round(now * 100) / 100);
            }
        });
    });
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
    startCounter();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="count">6.0</p>
<p class="count">600</p>
```

If you want to be able to use both, decimal and integer representation, you can do something like this (this snippet is also using `toFixed()` instead in order to represent "6.00" correctly):

```js
function startCounter(){
    $('.count').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 3000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                var $this = $(this),
                    isFloat = !!$(this).attr('data-float');
                $this.text(isFloat ? now.toFixed(2) : Math.round(now));
            }
        });
    });
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
    startCounter();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="count" data-float="true">6.0</p>
<p class="count">600</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the 2 decimal places all the time (even 6.00) you can use `toFixed(x)`. It will take any number an return a string with `x` decimal numbers.

```js
function startCounter(){
    $('.count').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 3000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(now.toFixed(2));
            }
        });
    });
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
    startCounter();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="count">6.0</p>
<p class="count">600</p>
```